# rails 3: display link as button?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, hyperlink

On some non-form pages, I have a few links that would look better as a button than a hyperlink...

I thought button_to instead of link_to would work, but buton_to seems to always be treated as a post.

Is there an easy way to simply replace a (non-submit) link with a button?

Comment: I have a custom style for my site's buttons, so, when I want a link to look like a button, I just apply that same CSS style to the `<a>`. Ta da.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

All you have to do is add a `:method => "get"` to the end of your button_to to get it to be treated like a link

### The button_to Way

Using a `users_path`

```
<%= button_to "BUTTON: link version", users_path, :method => "get" %>
```

### The CSS Way

Or instead of actually inserting a form into your html (which is what button_to actually does) you could go with the cleaner (from a web design perspective) method and actually just style the link in a way to make it look like a button
This has several benefits

Keeps forms out of your HTML, when they really shouldn't be there

Keeps your erb clean and normal, no surprises

Awesomely flexible, you can make them look the way you want

[Here is a great article on how to do it](http://www.oscaralexander.com/tutorials/how-to-make-sexy-buttons-with-css.html) and here is a little snippet of that code, really just depends on playing around with the border, padding and background image

```
a.button {
  background: transparent url('bg_button_a.gif') no-repeat scroll top right;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
  height: 24px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  padding-right: 18px; /* sliding doors padding */
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

The code comes from the link above. Whichever method you choose should work fine, enjoy!

Comment: You could also just style the link to look like your buttons, if the only goal is to make a link look like a button, and not to actually stick a full-blown form in your page.

Comment: Yes, but the question did specifically ask for a way to use the buttons as links. And the comment above identified that issue.

Comment: Edited the post to address your concerns

Comment: extraordinary answer, thank you! the css approach is very very cool

Comment: is it compulsory to use get method? what about post method?

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: Drug Joshi's answer below is what I was looking for. (Even with "get" a button_to will create a form, which can break things like turbolinks. The `link_to` answer below is simple and works.)

Answer (score 20):

I think all you want here is the just view. and if that is the case then you can just add a class to the class object in link

`<%= link_to 'Add Class', new_subject_path, class: "btn btn-primary"%>`

Comment: This should be the best answer.

Comment: You may want to mention that the classes you're using are coming from Bootstrap.

Answer (score 12):

I recently had to do this because my form was acting differently for link_to than it was with button_to and I needed the functionality the link provided. The best solution I found does not use CSS at all but instead calls .html_safe to escape the html in the ruby code and properly display the link as a button. What you want to do is this:

```
<%= link_to "<button>This is a button</button>".html_safe, some_path, :id => "button_id", :class => "button_class" %>
```

Comment: For future reference, you can pass a block to the `link_to` helper when dealing with embedded HTML, it works out to be a much cleaner looking solution.

Comment: Nearly 10 years later.  Perhaps a lot has changed in rails, but this is a really neat and easy solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### If all you want to do is make a link look like a button.

Changing `link_to` to `button_to` is all I needed to do.

Comment: as my post indicated, when I tried that is always used Post instead of Get