# rails 3 - Add a Button that won't submit a form

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to add a few "next" and "back" buttons to a form. The Idea is to divide the filling-out process into several steps and with these buttons, the div of the current step gets hidden and the next resp. previous step is displayed.

My Problem is that when I add buttons in the following way...

```
<button class="proceed_button" id="loan_information">Proceed</button>
<button class="cancel_button" id="loan_information">Cancel</button>
```

... they submit the form.
Is every button inside a form-tag considered to be a submit-button?
If so, how can I change this behavior?
If not, why are they doing it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the solution is that the button needs a type.

```
<button type="button" class="proceed_button" id="loan_information">Proceed</button>
<button type="button" class="cancel_button" id="loan_information">Cancel</button>
```

Like this, it won't submit the form anymore.

According to http://w3schools.com/html5/att_button_type.asp the default type is depending on the browser, so you should always specify the type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you want a button, maybe you want it to *look* like a button. Either way, refer to this post: [rails 3: display link as button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247491/rails-3-display-link-as-button)

Once you have your button, you'll need to update your javascript to prevent anything from happening when it's clicked (assuming you have jquery). It's still nice to provide a real fallback for those dinosaurs without js, so assuming your proceed button submits for users without js, for those with js you'd do something like:

```
$('#proceed_button').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); // Show and hide your divs here });
```

Also note that in your posted code you should not have two buttons with the same id, your ids and classes look swapped.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've found a solution, it was pretty easy. I could not add it until know since I have limited reputation points. I will add it now. Thanks for the advice with the id and classes.

Comment: The Idea behing the id- and class swap was that all the proceed-buttons get the same function on onClick and to find out which of these buttons was clicked (or which step it is in, to be more precise) i access the id with $(this).attr('id'). All with the same class recieves the same behaviour. I always assumed that ID is somehow a "child" to class. class.id. You know what I mean?

Comment: That is incorrect though, ids should be unique, classes can be shared. It is both invalid html and xhtml to repeat ids. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp You can easily use class names with jquery - `$('.className').click()`