# Trying to make link_to look like button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to make the element created by `link_to` as a button.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247575/3120489) and I edited my code like this:

```
<%= button_to 'Edit', :action => 'edit', :id => product, :method => "get" %>
```

However, I get the error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/product/edit"
```

I have gone through many posts talking about this and I have seen the API but I don't seem to do this thing right.

**EDIT**

rake routes updated:

```
product_edit GET  /product/edit(.:format)      product#edit
```

Comment: post your rake routes for this controller then it will be easier for me to post the answer

Comment: I uploaded the route for edit

Comment: No I mean run command `rake routes` and paste here the outcome of it

Comment: Post your rake routes output.

Comment: ok I updated the route returned with `rake routes`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= button_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(product), :method => "get" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use some path helper (like `edit_product_path(product)` posted above) if you have `products` defined as `resources` in your `routes.rb`

Alternatively you can use the way you started, but you need to provide `controller` option to the link - you provided action name, but not the controller name.