# Rails: How can I make my buttons have the functionality of links without using CSS decorations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[I am attempting what was stated as the solution in this thread:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247491/rails-3-display-link-as-button)

```
<%= button_tag "Galleries", new_gallery_path, id: "create_gallery", method: "get" %>
<%= button_tag "Groups", new_group_path, id: "create_group", method: "get" %>
```

When I do this though I get an error which states:

> wrong number of arguments (3 for 0..2)

I tried removing the id property (since it said there were too many arguments) but I still received the same error. How can I make my buttons have the functionality of links without using CSS?

Comment: According to that thread they have used button_to instead of button_tag. see in this [Display link as button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247491/rails-3-display-link-as-button)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `button_tag` in your code, and in the example you provided they are using `button_to`. To get the same functionality with `button_tag` that they use in that example simply specify the path as an `action` property.

```
<%= button_tag "Galleries", action: new_gallery_path, id: "create_gallery", method: "get" %>
<%= button_tag "Groups", action: new_group_path, id: "create_group", method: "get" %>
```