# Ruby on Rails - how to add link to view through button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, button, link-to

i have the below code, and i just want to link my button to the next view

```
<button type="submit" class="login-button"><link_to home_page.html.erb></link_to>    
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

how can i fix this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rails 3: display link as button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247491/rails-3-display-link-as-button)

Comment: You can't link to a view directly. You will have to go through some route. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @John even the `link_to` is not good enough to be used standalone.

Comment: Feel free to like/upvote answer if it helped you. :)

Comment: Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have form_tag or form_for somewhere outside your button.

You could do it totally the Rails way like

```
<%= submit_tag("submit") %>
```

or if you prefer a link

```
<%= link_to 'submit', your_path, your_options %>
```

or a button

```
<%= button_to 'subimit, your_path, your_options %>
```

just have a look rails guides and you will find plenty of examples

Comment: link_to generate `<a>` but use requirement is `type="submit"` so i don't think it will work as per requirement.

Answer (score 0):

=> link_to generates a `<a>` tag, which is not `input type="submit"`.Use [button_to](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to), which generates a form with a `input type="submit"` button to the link.

Assuming path of home_page.html.erb is `homepage_path`(replace it with your path.)

```
<%= button_to home_page_path,class: "login-button", method: :get do%>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
<% end %>
```

Alternatively you can use like this:-

```
<%= button_to "<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>".html_safe, homepage_path, class: "login-button", method: :get %>
```

Comment: Still using the older ruby syntax for `Hash`: `:class => "login-button"` ?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Thanks for point me out, fat arrow syntax should not be used, but still it works, well i'll update the answer :)

Comment: @Gabbar: what do you mean, "should not be used"? It's not like this form is deprecated or anything. JFYI, the term here is "hashrocket", not "fat arrow"

Comment: So far as I know it's old syntax and it's not good practice to use that has rocket syntax . Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood, but if you need to link to another page you don't need a button, you need a link.

You can add a simple link to that url (not the page, but the route to that page) and style it as a button with css if you want to make it look as you like.

If you need to submit and elaborate some stuff calling a method from your controller, it depends:

1.If your controller is a simple controller you can manage it with a redirect_to at the end of your method

```
def method
  # your elaboration
  redirect_to :your_route
end
```

2.If it is an API controller and you call it from a javascript function, you can add to your callback a window.location.href to your route

```
success: (data) => {
 // your elaboration
 window.location.href = "path/to/your/page"
}
```